# How I can I construct this diagonal matrix by notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Imagine the following diagonal matrix:
$$\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}a\\
& \ddots\\
&& a\\
&&& b\\
&&&& \ddots\\
&&&&& b\\
&&&&&& \ddots
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
I need the entries $a$, $b$ etc. replicated equally many times $M$ along the diagonal of $\mathbf A$. Now, obviously there is a lot of redundancy in this matrix, and I would like to boil it down to a more compact description in which
$$\mathbf A = f(\mathbf a)$$
where
$$\mathbf a = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & \dots\end{bmatrix}$$
However, I still have not quite figured out what $f(\cdot)$ should be. I have thought of $\mathbf a \otimes \mathbf I_M$ (Kronecker product), but this becomes:
$$\mathbf a \otimes \mathbf I_M = \begin{bmatrix}a\\
& \ddots\\
&& a\\
b\\
& \ddots\\
&& b\\
& \vdots
\end{bmatrix},$$
so I am not quite there. Similarly, $\mathbf I_M \otimes \mathbf a$ does not quite fit the bill either:
$$\mathbf I_M \otimes \mathbf a= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a\\
& \mathbf a\\
&& \ddots\\
&&& \mathbf a
\end{bmatrix}$$

The central requirement here is that I would like to keep $\mathbf a$, but it is less important what $f$ I get.

Comment: I am mystified. Why not just make your own definition? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just hoping to find a simple way to describe $\mathbf A$ in terms of $\mathbf a$ instead of dragging around the definition of $\mathbf A$. $\mathbf a$ is going to be a variable in an optimisation problem and I think it will be technically "ugly" to define an optimisation problem in terms of a matrix variable that has a lot of redundancy in it. I do not want to have to constrain my problem just to require a lot of $\mathbf A$'s entries to be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found a way now: if we let:
$$\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf a) = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
& b\\
&& \ddots\end{bmatrix},$$
then
$$\mathbf A = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf a) \otimes \mathbf I_M$$

Comment: Using the all-ones vectors ${\tt1}_m$ rather than the identity matrix $I_m$ yields $$A=\operatorname{diag}\left(a\otimes{\tt1}_m\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Following [operation to get a diagonal matrix from a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1205127) and assuming $\mathbf a$ is a column vector with $n$ entries:

$$\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf a) = (\mathbf a\mathbf 1_n^T)\odot \mathbf I_n = (\mathbf 1_n \mathbf a^T)\odot \mathbf I_n$$

where $\mathbf 1_n$ is a column vector consisting of $n$ $1$s and $\odot$ is the Hadamard product. Then,

$$\mathbf A = \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf a) \otimes\mathbf I_M = \left((\mathbf a\mathbf 1_n^T)\odot \mathbf I_n\right)\otimes\mathbf I_M.$$

That said, this is kind of an ugly hack. Following almagest's suggestion, it might be better to make up some more compact notation, like $\Delta^M(\mathbf a)$.